# Remove space from \footcite before [prenote]

Tags: biblatex

I am using this LATEX Template from GitHub and a have a small problem:
https://github.com/andygrunwald/FOM-LaTeX-Template

If I don't have an [prenote] entry for a footnote quote, a space is inserted in the footnote. I would like to remove this space. Unfortunately I do not know how?

Here my latex code:

```
% Optionen für Biblatex
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
giveninits=false,
isbn=true,
url=true,
doi=false,
eprint=false,
maxbibnames=7, % Alle Autoren (kein et al.)
maxcitenames=2, % et al. ab dem 3. Autor
backref=false, % Rückverweise auf Zitatseiten
bibencoding=utf8, % wenn .bib in utf8, sonst ascii
bibwarn=true, % Warnung bei fehlerhafter bib-Datei
firstinits=true,
skipbib=false
}%

% et al. an Stelle von u.a.
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
}

% Klammern um das Jahr in der Fußnote
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{% 
  \iffieldundef{labelyear} 
    {} 
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{% 
       \mkbibparens{% 
         \printfield{labelyear}% 
         \printfield{extrayear}}}}}

\DeclareNameFormat{last-first}{%
  \iffirstinits
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffix}
    }
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiven}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffix}
    }%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

% Alternative Notation der Fußnoten
% Zeigt sowohl den Nachnamen als auch den Vornamen an
% Beispiel: \fullfootcite[Vgl. ][Seite 5]{Tanenbaum.2003}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullfootcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printnames[sortname][1-1]{author}%
    \addspace (\printfield{year})}
  {\addsemicolon\space}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
  
% TEST
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printnames[sortname][1-1]{author}%
    \addspace (\printfield{year})}
  {\addsemicolon\space}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

%Autoren (Nachname, Vorname)
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

%Reihenfolge von publisher, year, address verändern
% Achtung, bisher nur für den Typ @book definiert

%% Definiert @Book Eintrag
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  %\space
  (\printfield{year})%
  \setunit*{:\space}%  
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit*{,\space}%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \setunit*{,\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \printfield{year}%
%  \setunit*{,\space}% 
%  \printfield{isbn}%
  \finentry}

%% Definiert @Online Eintrag
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \setunit*{(}%
  \printfield{year}%
  \setunit*{):\space}%
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \printfield{url}%
  \setunit*{,\space Aufruf am:\space}%
  \printfield{urlday}%
  \setunit*{.}%
  \printfield{urlmonth}%
  \setunit*{.}%
  \printfield{urlyear}%
  \finentry}
  
%% Definiert @misc Eintrag --> Literaturverwaltung mit Citavi
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{misc}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \setunit*{\space(}%
 \printfield{year}%
  \setunit*{):\space}%
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \printfield{url}%
  \setunit*{,\space Aufruf am:\space}%
  \printfield{urlday}%
  \setunit*{.}%
  \printfield{urlmonth}%
  \setunit*{.}%
  \printfield{urlyear}%
  \finentry}

%% Definiert @Article Eintrag
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \setunit*{\space (}%
  \printfield{year}%  
  \setunit*{):\space}%
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit*{\space in:\space}%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{,\space}%
  \printfield{year}%
  \setunit*{,\space}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{. Jg ,\space Nr. }%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit*{,\space}%
  \printfield{pages}%  
  \finentry}  

%% Definiert @InProceedings Eintrag
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
    \printnames{author}%
    \setunit*{,\space (}%
    \printfield{year}\newunit{)}%
    \newunit\newblockpunct
    \printfield{title}%
    \setunit*{\space}%  
    \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
    \setunit*{,\space}%
    \printfield{isbn}%
    \setunit*{,\space}% 
    \printfield{doi}%
    \finentry}
    
%% Definiert Gesetzestext
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{gesetz}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \setunit*{\space(}%
 \printfield{year}%
  \setunit*{):\space}%
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \printfield{url}%
  \setunit*{,\space Aufruf am:\space}%
  \printfield{urlday}%
  \setunit*{.}%
  \printfield{urlmonth}%
  \setunit*{.}%
  \printfield{urlyear}%
  \finentry}

%Doppelpunkt nach dem letzten Autor
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace }

%Komma an Stelle des Punktes
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

%Autoren durch Semikolon trennen
\newcommand*{\bibmultinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}%
\newcommand*{\bibfinalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}%
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \let\multinamedelim\bibmultinamedelim
  \let\finalnamedelim\bibfinalnamedelim
}

%Titel nicht kursiv anzeigen
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1\isdot}
```

Here is an example quote:

```
~\footcite[Vgl. ][S. 1-9]{Nakamoto.2009}
~\footcite[][S. 1-9]{Nakamoto.2009}
```

Result:

[image]

Any idea? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two sources of spurious spaces in your example.

1. The definition `\DeclareNameFormat{last-first}` creates a spurious space. But the definition is basically the same as in `biblatex.def`, so you can just remove the whole block

   ```
   \DeclareNameFormat{last-first}{%
     \iffirstinits
       {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
           {\namepartfamily}
           {\namepartgiveni}
           {\namepartprefix}
           {\namepartsuffix}
       }
       {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
           {\namepartfamily}
           {\namepartgiven}
           {\namepartprefix}
           {\namepartsuffix}
       }%
     \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
   ```
2. There is a space after `Vgl.` in `\footcite[Vgl. ][S. 1-9]{Nakamoto.2009}`. It should just read

   ```
    \footcite[Vgl.][1-9]{Nakamoto.2009}
   ```

   (You also don't need the explicit `S.`. A page prefix will be added automatically depending on the currently selected language.)

Comment: Vielen Dank moewe! Thank you very much!

That was the solution.